# Downloading a file in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have stored a pdf file at sites/default/files/1.pdf. How can I allow users to download the file? At the moment, I am using the following method:

```
<ol>
<li><a href="1.pdf">File Download</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

To download the files give the full path of the files.Something like below:

```
<ol>
<li><a href="' . $base_url . ' /sites/default/files/1.pdf'">File Download</a></li>
</ol>
```

Or try like below by using fid.

```
 $uri = 'public://foldername/1.pdf;
 $files = file_load_multiple(array(), array('uri' => $uri));
 $file = reset($files);
 <a href="' . $base_url . '/file/' . $file->fid . '" title="Download ' . 1.pdf . '">' File download '</a>';
```

Comment: Have you tried by adding same way as I mentioned or specific path of ur files? Bcz I have mentioned something like generic. You try by adding full path to ur file.